# GetTcpTable equivalent on Linux

Tags: c, linux

Is there an API call on Linux which returns currently opened TCP connections on the system (like [GetTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026(VS.85).aspx) call on Windows)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per UNIX philosophy of "everything is a file", you can get what you want from reading `/proc/net/tcp`.

Comment: "netstat -t" from the command line (or through an exec) also works.

Comment: ..but doesn't do quite the same thing :)

Comment: Netstat reads the same file anyway, so you might as well go directly to the source.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out netstat -t (for TCP). `Man netstat` will give you all the options.

Comment: Whoops, other people already commented about this. Well, you should really check it out.

Comment: No worries :) I only did it as a comment because /proc/net/tcp seems more straightforward for checking connections programmatically.